# calling a route function in node.js without form action

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In node.js, express.js application, when a form action takes place it calls a route function as shown-

```
<form action="/home">
....
</form>
```

will call the route function with route as '/home' in index.js(or some other .js file)-

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
...
});
```

Is there a way to call this route function without form action?
Is there other name for what I am referring as "route function"?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to ask... do you simply want the webpage to make an HTTP request using JavaScript rather than physically submitting a form to create the HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, but not necessarily a webpage to make an HTTP request.

Comment: Can a JavaScript function in app.js make a call to the routing function specified above?

Comment: Right, so then you just need any client (could be a webpage, could be a script running somewhere else) to create an HTTP request pointing to your Express server at that route.

Comment: Is your question more that you can't directly call the handling function? As in, you don't necessarily need the Express route -- just that anonymous handler method?

Comment: I found a way to call the router function using- `var request = require("request");
...
request(link, function(e,res,body{...}));`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Do you want to just link people to the /home page? Because in that case you can just use an anchor tag.

If you want to receive data from the /home api call, you can use AJAX to do so. [See here for info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: In my express.js, node.js application, I wanted to make a call to the router function- `router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
...
});` from a JavaScript function in app.js. I found out a way to do so, I'm using `var request = require("request");
...
request(link, function(e,res,body{...}));`